# How to prevent dates in the future with my Student table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```html
-- Create a trigger that will prevent  an update to a student table if EnrolledDate is in the future

USE College ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  Student_Before_Update; 

DELIMITER $$

        CREATE TRIGGER Student_Before_Update
        BEFORE UPDATE ON Student 
        FOR EACH ROW 
        
      BEGIN 
      
 IF NEW.EnrolledDate > '2016-10-18'  THEN 
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'Enrolled date may not be in the future';
  END IF; 

      END $$

DELIMITER ;

UPDATE Student
SET EnrolledDate= DATE(now())
WHERE ID= 1; 

UPDATE Student
SET EnrolledDate= DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE ID=1;
```

Hello Everyone,

I am working on creating a BEFORE UPDATE trigger which should display an error 
message if I UPDATE a student's EnrolledDate with a future date. For example, the last inserted EnrolledDate in the Student table is '2016-04-17', so any other record after that date should flag an error message saying "Enrolled Date may not be in the future." I have been literally working on this for hours, but I am not getting anyway. Can someone please help me? Here is my code so far.

Comment: How? You're comparing to a hard coded date way in the past (2016-10-18) instead of now.

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher Should I use the GetDate()? I tried that but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: ```DATE(NOW())``` should work.

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher What would I need to do to fix my if statement if the EnrolledDate is passed the day after today? My if statement doesn't produce the right results.

Comment: See my answer....

Comment: Incidentally, you don't really need a trigger for this. You can build the logic into the query itself. Then, if the query creates no rows, you know that there's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- Create a trigger that will prevent  an update to a student table if EnrolledDate is in the future

USE College ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  Student_Before_Update; 

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER Student_Before_Update
BEFORE UPDATE ON Student 
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

    IF DATE_FORMAT(NEW.EnrolledDate,'%Y-%m-%d') > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')  THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'Enrolled date may not be in the future';
    END IF; 

END $$

DELIMITER ;

UPDATE Student
SET EnrolledDate= DATE(now())
WHERE ID= 1; 

UPDATE Student
SET EnrolledDate= DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE ID=1;
```

Comment: -But it is not supposed to display an error Message if the EnrolledDate is NOT passed the current date. RIght? And yet it does.

Comment: Correct. But if your column is a timestamp, which includes time, you'll need to drop the time part off of both the date and now. That is, if you only want to compare the dates.

Comment: My EnrolledDate is an date datatype.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: How do I drop the time off the date?

Comment: It still is producing the errorMessage. It shouldn't be doing that if the EnrolledDate which is now IS NOT greater than the NOW date.

Comment: @ Sloan Thrasher -Your method works, but the second UPDATE should be displaying an error message. I am trying to get rid of the time in the second update. How do I get rid of it? Because MySQL doesn't like how it's  not a actual date. The time part is biggest problem for me.

Comment: As I said, did you try my updated answer? It compares just the dates.

Comment: @ Sloan Thrasher yes, but the second UPDATE should display the error. The first UPDATE is fine. If I convert the second  DATE_ADD() into just date would it then display the error Message I want.

Comment: @ I think if I add this:  AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) to the if statement, it produces what I what. Any suggestions about that?

Comment: I think if I change NOW() to CURDATE with the second UPDATE statement, it produces the error for the second UPDATE statement and the first update statement changes the EnrolledDate to the today's date. I solved my own problem. Thanks and let me know what you think about it.

Comment: In DATE_FORMAT(NOW()),'%Y-%m-%d') there's a ) that should be removed.